# Intellij GUI Designer doesn't generate $$$setupUI$$$ method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm working on something in Intellij-ScalaPlugin and I want to modify something in the Settings Panel. I changed the text from an existing label and after compiling the project the $$$setupUI$$$ method is unchanged.

[image: GUI Designer settings]

I'm trying to change the text from the label shown in this image, but after compilation the $$$setupUI$$$ method is not changed.
[image: I'm trying to change the text from the label shown in this image]

What can I do in order to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure GUI Designer to generate source code instead of instrumenting binary classes:

[image: designer]

For this specific plug-in project you will also need to disable `Use SBT shell for build and import` option.

Comment: My settings are exactly the same. I posted a link with my settings.

Comment: @Maris is the form bound to the class?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes

Comment: @Maris please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder I edited my question. So now you can see there is a link with a photo that describes what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Maris does it help if you disable `Use SBT shell for build and import` option and rebuild?